# AWS Bucket Policy Error: Policy has invalid action

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I have a very basic goal: to share all content of my bucket to a list of specific users, read only. This used to work with a tool called s3cmd. All I need to do was to add a user (identified by email) to the `Access Control List with Read Permission`, and they could list or download data smoothly.

But recently, this suddenly did not work anymore. The system just denies any attempt to access my bucket.

I then started thinking of editing the bucket policy. Here is the draft of my policy, generated by the Policy Generator (sensitive information is anonymized):

```json
    {
      "Id": "Policy123456789",
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Sid": "Stmt1512705836469",
          "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:ListObjects"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname",
          "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
              "arn:aws:iam::anotheruserid:user/admin"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

When I click `save`, I get a "**Policy has invalid action**" error. I then tried to remove "*ListObjects*" so the policy becomes

```json
    {
      "Id": "Policy123456789",
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Sid": "Stmt1512705836469",
          "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname",
          "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
              "arn:aws:iam::anotheruserid:user/admin"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

and got another error message "**Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement**".

These two errors do not make sense to me. Please correct me if I am wrong. If I am not in the right direction, please help me.

BTW: I tried to follow the tutorial at
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html
but wasn't successful. By using the following bucket policy:

```Json
    {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
          {
             "Sid": "Example permissions",
             "Effect": "Allow",
             "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::AccountB-ID:root"
             },
             "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket"
             ],
             "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket"
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
```

I got an error message when using awscli of AccountB to execute "**aws s3 ls s3://examplebucket**".
The error message was "**An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied**".

This confuses me. If I add *ListObjects*, I got an `"invalid" error`.
If I remove the "**ListObjects**", another user could not read my bucket content.

What should I do?

Comment: It's like playing whack-a-mole

Answer (score 13):

I suspect that the Policy Editor has become smarter when it comes to operations that operate **on buckets** as opposed to **within buckets**.

Also, `ListObjects` seems to be upsetting it, so leave it out.

This policy allows the contents of a bucket to be listed and objects retrieved:

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Statement1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ],
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/user-name"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

`ListBucket` operates on the Bucket.

`GetObject` operates on the *contents* of a bucket.

It could be written as two separate statements within the policy (one on the bucket, one on the contents of the bucket), but it's often easier to write it as above.

Comment: [`s3:ListObjects`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_s3.html) seems to be a documentation error. `s3:ListBucket` is the unfortunate name for the action that allows listing the objects in a bucket. I submitted a docs feedback on it.

Comment: Thanks! I followed your code and now S3 accepts my bucket policy. However, I still cannot get the third user accessing my bucket. The command I tried to run was "aws s3 ls s3://examplebucket", and the error I got was "An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied". Is there anything the third user need to do?

Comment: Following up my previous comment, `s3:ListObjects` apparently was indeed a documentation error.  That action no longer appears on the linked page.

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts to [granting bucket access to a user in another account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html).

1. Set the correct policy on the bucket.
2. Allow the IAM user in the other account to perform the necessary operations on the bucket.

This does seem redundant, but both are required.

Additionally, the `ListObjects` action is deceiving, especially as the [awspolicygen tool](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) also lists it as a permission.  However in the [documentation about S3 permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-with-s3-actions.html#using-with-s3-actions-related-to-buckets) you'll find that `ListObjects` is in fact an operation controlled by the `ListBucket` permission.

In the second example that you provide I suspect the reason you were unsuccessful was because the requesting user may not have the `ListBucket` privilege for your bucket.  Additionally, I do believe the `GetBucketLocation` is not strictly required for your scenario, however if you want them to get items from the bucket you would need to grant `GetObject` privileges.