# How to allow Amazon S3 access from specific IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying this policy to allow users to Put and List object access with a particular IP (56.160.12.114) only and all the rest should have only Get access. But this policy is not working for me:

```
{
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPDeny",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-wicked-awesome-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "56.160.12.114/28"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This policy is saying: *Deny access to anyone who is not using this range of IP addresses*

That's fine, but you will also need a policy that *Allows* access, because the default behaviour is Deny. Thus, you are Denying people who are already denied by default.

A better way would be:

- Have default Deny access (happens automatically)
- Allow access based on IP

Something like this:

```
{
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-wicked-awesome-bucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "56.160.12.114/28"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Please note, however, that this is granting `s3:*` access to *any system* that is coming from that range of IP addresses (including whatever is connected to that network range). Make sure you're okay with that.

**Update:**

If you only want to grant the user the ability to Put and List the object, then use:

```
{
    "Id": "S3PolicyId1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "IPAllow",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::jstack-b",
                "arn:aws:s3:::jstack-b/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "56.160.12.114/28"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: hi John thanks for the reply. i have attached the given policy and access the bucket with ip 56.160.12.114. but i am able to delete the object. where as i want user should only put and list the object

Comment: Added a policy.

Comment: HI John tried above policy but getting error while save the policy

Comment: Updated. `ListObjects` wasn't happy, so I used `ListBucket` instead, as per [AWS Bucket Policy Error: Policy has invalid action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708780/174777)